# How to validate the value if it exist in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want first to check if the data is already in the database or not. So here is my code:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';

    $tc_course_name2 = strtoupper($_POST['tc_course_name']);
    $tc_course_code2 = strtoupper($_POST['tc_course_code']);

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(tc_course_name) FROM tc_courses WHERE tc_course_name = '{$tc_course_name2}'";
    $stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $fetch = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);

    if ($fetch > 0) {

        echo "Course Name Already Exist";
    }

    else {
        $query_update = "INSERT INTO tc_courses (tc_course_code,tc_course_name) VALUES('$tc_course_code2','$tc_course_name2')";  
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$query_update)) {
                header("Location: ../admin/add_new_training_course.php"); 
            }
        else {
            echo 'Something went wrong';
            }
    }

?>
```

In this code, it always run the `Course Name Already Exist` even it is not saved on the `database`. Can someone help me here? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `count(...)` function will always return a value, so when you use `mysqli_num_rows` it will always be `> 0` (the query returns row with the count() value - that value can be `0` or more...).

You should check the value of the `count(...)` to see if its `>0`

change this:

```
$fetch = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
if ($fetch > 0) {
    echo "Course Name Already Exist";
}
```

to

```
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
if ($fetch[0] > 0) {
    echo "Course Name Already Exist";
}
```

Comment: now it always run the `$query_update` even the value is already stored in the database

Comment: Are you sure the value is really stored in the database?

Comment: in my page, after you submit the form, all the value in the table were being fetched

Comment: Not sure I understand your reply.

Comment: `<?php

            while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".sprintf("%s", $tc_course_name)."</td>";
            echo "<td>".sprintf("%s", $tc_course_code)."</td>";


            echo '</tr>';
            }

            ?>`

sorry i got this on my page

Comment: I don't understand how it's related to the question.

Comment: because you are asking me how am i sure that value is really stored in database. every time i submit the form, it will direct me the page that contains that code

Comment: Try `var_dump($fetch);` before the `if` statement. What do you get?

Comment: i got this int(1)

Comment: Did you `var_dump($fetch);` or `var_dump($fetch[0]);`?

Comment: i used this `var_dump($fetch);`

Comment: So you obviously didn't use `$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);`, because the `mysqli_fetch_array` function return `array` and not `int`...

Comment: yes. i run your example and it always run the `$query_update`

Comment: something doesn't make sense here at all... do you still have `mysqli_num_rows` in your code?

Comment: so... you didn't read my answer. I **dont need** the `mysql_num_rows`, because this will **always** give you 1...

Comment: I really can't understand people who ask a question and don't take the time to read and understand the answers they get...

Comment: im really sorry about that. i did not fully understand your answer. sorry man

Comment: If you don't understand - ask for clarification... you should **change** the code you have (from `mysql_num_rows` to the end of the `if` block) with my code...

Comment: yes i already did and it worked now. thank you. i will accept your answer. thanks man and sorry

Comment: Added a clarification in my answer